# How to layout correctly

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

I just try to create my own layout. I used `UITableView` for my `UIViewController`. I have some JSON response from server. This is like detailed publication. Also i calculate my `UITableViewCell` height because my publication contain mix of images and text. I wrote own layout and recalculate when device in rotation.

```
for (UIView * sub in contentSubviews) {
    if([sub isKindOfClass:[PaddingLabel class]])
    {
        PaddingLabel *textPart = (PaddingLabel *)sub;
        reusableFrame = textPart.frame;
        reusableFrame.origin.y = partHeight;
        partHeight += textPart.frame.size.height;
        [textPart setFrame:reusableFrame];            
    } else if([sub isKindOfClass:[UIImageView class]])
    {
        UIImageView * imagePart = (UIImageView *)sub;
        reusableFrame = imagePart.frame;
        reusableFrame.origin.y = partHeight;
        reusableFrame.origin.x = screenWidth/2 - imageSize.width/2;
        reusableFrame.size.width = imageSize.width;
        reusableFrame.size.height = imageSize.height;
        [imagePart setFrame:reusableFrame];
        partHeight += imagePart.frame.size.height;
    }
}
```

But I have some issue.
When device change orientation state `UIScrollView` offset is same as was. I don't know how to change it.
Before rotation:

[image]

After rotation:

[image]

I want to save visible elements in rect.
Suggest pls.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of choices, depending on what you wish to show after rotation. One possible solution is get contentOffset.y/contentSize.height before rotation, then multiple it to new contentSize.height to derive the new contentOffset.y. Or if you wish to keep a specific element visible before and after rotation, get the difference between element_view.frame.origin.y and contentOffset.y, then set new contentOffset.y to be element_view.frame.origin.y + difference.